# Invalid syntax error on python version while running python idle

Tags: python, sockets, syntax-error, python-idle

I am working on a tcp client-server python socket program where I have written server code to sent a simple message to the client . However when I run the server side in python idle I get invlalid syntax error and a red mark on the python version . I don't know where the problem is and I would appreciate your help with this specific task .
Image where error happens : 
[image]

I press run and then run module and I get : 
[image]

My code :

Server :

```
   import sys
   from socket import *
   serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
   serverSocket.bind(('localhost',1234))
   serverSocket.listen()
   data = "Network labs"
   while 1 :
     connectionSocket ,addr = serverSocket.accept()
     connectionSocket.send(data)
     connectionSocket.close()
```

Client :

```
   import sys
   from socket import *
   clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
   server_address=('localhost',1234)
   clientSocket.connect(server_address)
   sentence = clientSocket.recv(1024)
   print(sentence)
   clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: Your image doesn't show the syntax error. Could you replace it with one that does? It would also be helpful to type out the text of the syntax error message in another code block for easy readability.

Comment: @DavidZ it does . It is the red mark on top left  on the python version 3.8.3 on the first 3

Comment: That's not a syntax error though. I'm asking for the message that says `SyntaxError` and gives some information about what Python considers to have been the exact error, which is always printed by Python when you enter code with invalid syntax.

Comment: @DavidZ A window pops up saying "error invalid syntax" then it marks the 3 on the version

Comment: Can you please show the actual error? How are you running this code?

Comment: @DavidZ here is a screenshot of the error

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Unfortunately I still don't know why this is happening, but given the information you added, perhaps someone else will.

Comment: Have you tried to run it in a normal python REPL instead of the IDLE?

Comment: @pkqxdd yes on Replit and I got an error on    clientSocket.connect(server_address) that the host refuses connection

Comment: @pkqxdd If Vasilis has tried to run a saved shell session as Python code in any other code editor that runs python code, or from the code line, python would have reported the same SyntaxError in the same location.  This has nothing to do with IDLE itself.

Comment: @DavidZ Python says that 'Python 3', run as python code, is a SyntaxError at the '3' because '3' following a name is not valid Python code, regardless of how one tells python to run it.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy That's true. However, as someone who doesn't use IDLE, it's not even slightly evident to me that the saved shell session is actually being run as Python code. The question includes a typed-out version of the code which is not a shell session. So in the absence of any reason to think otherwise, I assumed that what the OP had typed out accurately represented the file they were trying to run (or, at least, if that weren't the case, I was hoping someone more familiar with IDLE would notice, as it seems you did).

Comment: @TerryJanReedy ah yes that makes sense. I did not notice the OP was trying to run a python session log as a script. I assumed that the OP was in REPL when I saw the `>>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to run the log of a shell session, complete with non-code startup message text and non-code prompts as python code. But the session log is not python code.  "Python" might be, but "Python 3" is not valid code and so python reports a SyntaxError.  This has nothing to do with running the code from an IDLE editor.  If you run server.py from a command line or from any other python-aware editor or IDE, you would see the same.

To run server.py, you must remove the non-code parts -- the startup message and prompts.  In general, you would also have to remove output, but there is none in your example.  So you should end up with

```
import sys
from socked import *
...
```

In other words, the cleaned-up server code you listed in your question, which is not the code you ran in the screenshot to get the error message.

Comment: I have . Now I get unexpected indent before import sys

Comment: As you posted the code, it has 3 spaces of indent (beyond the 4 spaces to signal 'code' to SO.  If you run with *any* indent before 'import sys', you get that message.

Comment: I mean indents before 'while'.  Your posted code has an extra 3 spaces of indent for every line that will prevent execution if copied and pasted.  You could edit it out.  I don't know what you actually ran.